# Input layer size is not matching with the image size in MTCNN

Tags: image-resizing

I am using detector.detect_faces() function of MTCNN and getting following error -

detector = mtcnn.MTCNN()
results = detector.detect_faces(pixels)

Input 0 of layer "model_6" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, None, None, 3), found shape=(None, 276, 375, 4)

Comment: Please tag the language you're using. Is it pytorch, tensorflow...? Your question lacks few formatting too.